# Filter a word list using a stop words file

Tags: awk, sed

So I have a text file with a random text, and I need to list all the words present in that file, but filtering all the words common to my stop words file. What commands can I use for this?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to show some sample input and sample output. This sounds like a job for [tag:grep]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a "word" is a string surrounded by whitespace, you could change all whitespace into newlines, sort the result and remove duplicates.  Then it's just a matter of removing the stop words from that list.

```bsh
tr -s '[:space:]' '[\n*]' <textfile |
sort -fu |
grep -v -Fix -f stopwords
```

The `tr` command changes all space-like characters into newlines and squeezes multiple consecutive newlines into one.  This list of one word per line is then sorted and duplicates of words are removed (ignoring case with `-f`).

You could also try `'[:space:][:punct:]'` as the first argument to `tr` to split the text into words on both space-like characters and punctuation characters, or use an explicit list of characters like `' ,.!?'`.

The list of sorted unique words is then compared to the words in `stopwords` (a file containing lines with one stop-word per line; change to whatever file you have), and words with no match in that list are kept.

The `-F` option to `grep` forces the utility to treat the patterns as *strings* rather than as regular expressions. The `-i` option makes it use case-insensitive matching.  The `-x` option lets us only accept full line matches (not sub-string matches).  The `-v` option inverts the usual sense of the match, so that lines *not* matching are retained, and `-f` makes `grep` read patterns from the named file.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question without knowing what both of the files look like.

But this oneliner should do the trick:

```
comm -3 <(sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' random.txt | sort | uniq) <(sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' stopwords.txt | sort | uniq)
```

`comm -3` will compare two sorted files line by line and suppress lines that appear in both files.

`<(...)` is a bash-trick that presents the output of a command as a file to another command. So what I'm doing here is producing a sorted list of words from both of the files:

`sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' random.txt` converts all spaces and tabs to linbreaks. Great! One word per line.

`sort` does just that and sorts those lines.

`uniq` makes sure every word appears only once.

Or you could use `tr` instead of `sed`:

```
comm -3 <(tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' < random.txt | sort | uniq) <(tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' < stopwords.txt | sort | uniq)
```

That could be faster, if you have very large files.

Comment: `sort | uniq` = `sort -u` and you should mention that requires GNU sed for `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

Making a bunch of assumptions since you didn't provide any sample input/output - with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='[^[:alpha:]]*[[:space:]]+[^[:alpha:]]*' '
     {lc=tolower($0)} NR==FNR{a[lc]++; next} !a[lc]++
' stop_words random_text
```

e.g. with this input:

```
$ head stop_words random_text
==> stop_words <==
a Of in at As
The by I on

==> random_text <==
I wandered lonely as a cloud
That floats on high o'er vales and hills,
When all at once I saw a crowd,
A host, of golden daffodils;
I wandered lonely as a cloud
When all at once I saw a crowd,
```

```
$ awk -v RS='[^[:alpha:]]*[[:space:]]+[^[:alpha:]]*' '{lc=tolower($0)} NR==FNR{a[lc]++; next} !a[lc]++' stop_words random_text
wandered
lonely
cloud
That
floats
high
o'er
vales
and
hills
When
all
once
saw
crowd
host
golden
daffodils
```